# Implement Vlookup formula on VBA, and handle error 1004

Tags: vba, error-handling, vlookup

I start my adventure with VBA. I would like to create formula on VBA, use vlookup but something is going wrong with this.
Also I would like to implement vlookup for cells, when 
cells from deferent column will be filled

( for example if WB_WS_Pricing.Range("A4")<>0 then 
WB_WS_PRICING.Range("CX4") = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Delivering!E4,DATA!A:I,9,0),"")"

Sub formula()

```
Set WB_CMSO_MASS_IBERIA = ThisWorkbook
Set WB = ThisWorkbook

    Set WB_WS_PRICING = WB.Sheets("Pricing")
    Set WB_WS_HEADER = WB.Sheets("Header")
    Set WB_WS_DATA = WB.Sheets("DATA")
    Set WB_WS_Extension = WB.Sheets("Extension")
    Set WB_WS_DELIVERING = WB.Sheets("Delivering")


  WB_WS_PRICING.Range("CX4") = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Delivering!E4,DATA!A:I,9,0),"")"




   End Sub
```

Enyone has idea what is wrong?? For me the formula seems be fine...

Comment: `""` needs to be `""""`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes in your formula with an extra quote in front of each (ie """" not "")

`WB_WS_PRICING.Range("CX4") = "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(Delivering!E4,DATA!A:I,9,0),"""")"`